# Is this a huge problem in my shower?

Tags: shower, leak, grout, crack

[image: floor tile]

Floor grout crack^^

[image]

Wall cracks

New construction (built in 2022) - 1.5 years old.

Noticed cracks in my grout in the shower and then noticed a crack in the grout on the floor. I showered once in the morning and then not anymore after that after noticing the cracks.

There are drops of water coming out, particularly when i tap the tile ABOVE where the crack on the floor is.

I know grout is porous and so was wondering if this was normal. I believe theres a moisture barrier behind the wall. My thoughts were to wait till it drys - then patchup/regrout some of the cracking on the wall and floor.

My concern is theres still droplets of water slowly coming out of the floor grout crack. I don't think theres a leak as I checked around and below the floor of this shower.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

I would have expected less water with a small crack like that.  So, I would be inclined to think that there is a leak.

- While grout is porous, they add a compound to make it water proof (downunder anyway).  But water will get in via the cracks.
- If you are able to not use the shower for a few days, do that and see if there is still water at the bottom.  if there isn't then its just the grout.
- I would get it repaired soon.  Even though there should be waterproofing under/behind the tiles, it is best not to test it but letting water get behind the tiles.
- Its best practice (again downunder) to have one vertical grout line flexible, to allow for expansion/contraction and very slight movement.

Comment: thanks i let it go for a few days and it dried. i regrouted the wall (there were multiple cracks like the one i shown) and i think im good now

Answer (score 0):

Grout is cosmetic, i.e. it performs no essential waterproofing function in a properly constructed shower enclosure. Then again, bad shower installs are common as dirt.